# PowerShell: Escaping open square bracket using Replace doesn't work

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to escape a square bracket in the file name by masking it to check file existence (including subfolders), but it doesn't work.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\somepath" -Directory | Where-Object { (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -File).Name -like "somestring [somenumber].*".Replace('[', '``[')}
```

However, this works (doesn't include subfolder):

```
Test-Path -Path "D:\somepath\subfolder\somestring [somenumber].*".Replace('[', '``[') -PathType Leaf
```

and this works too (hard coded):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\somepath" -Directory | Where-Object { (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -File).Name -like "somestring ``[somenumber].*"}
```

Any idea why is that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\SomePath" -Filter '*[*' -Recurse | ForEach-Object { $_.FullName -replace '\[', '``[' }`.

Comment: If I understood correctly, I can just update my code to: `"D:\somepath" -Directory | Where-Object { (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -File).Name -like ("somestring [somenumber].*" -replace '\[', '``[') )}`, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: No, that is not what I said.. `"D:\somepath" -Directory` is what?? You need to use tht `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet like I did. Have you tried it at all?

Comment: Is D:\somepath a command?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use doublequotes, the backquote will be taken literally.  You have one too many backquotes.  Check what you do piece by piece and make sure it works.

```
'['.replace('[','`[') 
`[

'['.replace('[','``[')                                                                                                       
``[
```

This works for me, backquoting the open square bracket.

```
get-childitem | where name -like '*`[*'
get-childitem | where name -like 'file `[1].*'
get-childitem | where name -match 'file \[1]'
```

This is little known, but -like can use square brackets as a wildcard:

```
get-childitem | where name -like '[a-f]*'
```

Those filenames are a hassle in powershell.  I would rename them.  You would have trouble creating one with a similar name in powershell.